# html5 canvas context .fillStyle not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Just giving canvas a go for the first time with the intention of creating a game. I have an image displaying but oddly the fillStyle method doesn't seem to be working. ( At least the canvas background is still white in google chrome.)

Note that in my code the canvas var is actually the canvas elements 2d context, maybe that's where i'm getting myself confused? i can't see the problem, would appreciate if anyone else could.

LD24.js:

```
const FPS = 30;
var canvasWidth = 0;
var canvasHeight = 0;
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;
var smiley = new Image();
smiley.src = "http://javascript-tutorials.googlecode.com/files/jsplatformer1-smiley.jpg";

var canvas = null;
window.onload = init; //set init function to be called onload

function init(){
    canvasWidth = document.getElementById('canvas').width;
    canvasHeight = document.getElementById('canvas').height;
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    setInterval(function(){
        update();
        draw();
    }, 1000/FPS);
}

function update(){

}
function draw()
{
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    canvas.fillStyle = "#FFAA33"; //orange fill
    canvas.drawImage(smiley, xPos, yPos);

}
```

LD24.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="LD24.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>



<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
    <p> Your browser does not support the canvas element needed to play this game :(</p>
</canvas>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 notes:

1. `fillStyle` does not cause your canvas to be filled. It means that when you **fill** a **shape** it will be filled with that color. Therefore you need to write `canvas.fillRect( xPos, yPos, width, height)`.
2. Wait until your image actually loads, otherwise the rendering may be inconsistent or buggy.
3. Careful of cross-domain images used in your canvas - most browsers will throw a security exception and stop executing your code.

Comment: Doh cant believe i missed that thank you! How can i check that the image has loaded? and yeah i'll be sure to use my own image soon enough.

Comment: Please note that the `.fillRect()` method is a method of the canvas' 2D context, not the canvas itself as (probably accidentally) mentioned in this answer!

Comment: @TimS. I simply followed the variable name from the question. I see how that could be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Wait till image loads as well:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    handleLoadedTexture(img);
};
img.src = "image.png";

function handleLoadedTexture(img) {
    //call loop etc that uses image
};
```

Comment: I've discovered an issue with fillStyle and fillRect() in Chrome. If I specify ctx.fillStyle="rgba(0,0,0,0)", what I end up getting instead is a fillStyle of rgba(0,0,0,1). Which results in subsequent rendering, relying upon the canvas being filled with transparent black, going haywire. Is this a known Chrome bug, or have I found something new?

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you were just missing

```
canvas.fill();
```

after

```
canvas.drawImage(smiley, xPos, yPos);
```